# Listview con un icono y texto

Tags: android, webservice, listview, android-imageview

Tengo un `Listview` que me trae un campo de texto de un **servidor Web** y lo muestra en el respectivo `listview ahora el asunto es que deseo agregar un icono mas el texto al lisview, pero hay que considerar que el icono se agregara siempre y cuando encuentre texto.

```
 private class AsyncRefrescar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(VerPreguntas.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();



    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/Verpregunta/mostrarpre.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {


            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();


            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }


                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        if(result.equals("unsuccessful")) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(VerPreguntas.this);
            alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
            alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar las preguntas. Intentelo de nuevo.");
            alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertaDeError.create();
            alertaDeError.show();
        }else{
            //Existen Datos

            List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Parsea la respuesta obtenida por el Asynctask
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
                try {
                    preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String pregunta = null;
                try {
                    pregunta = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                preguntas.add(pregunta);
            }
            //crear el Adapter.
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(VerPreguntas.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
            //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
            mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);



        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Si el control funciona solo si tiene Texto, podrias hacer una "Mexicanada", se me ocurre poner de texto un "." y ponerlo del color del fondo, para que no omita cuando no haya texto, o un espacio en blanco.

Comment: El punto principal es añadir un icono mas el texto, pero el texto lo recoge de un webservice, pero en la base solo se carga el texto no almacena imagen

Comment: Aaaaa ya te entiendo, solo quieres agregarle el icono, si no hay texto que no haga nada.... disculpa no lo capte antes.

Comment: tranquila descuida a cualquiera le pasa jaja si eso deseo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para lograr esto debes hacer un `CustomAdapter` para tu `listview`

Primero creas el layout con el cual quieres que cada item de tu lista tenga, es el formato visual que quieres darle a cada uno de tus items.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Marshmallow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

En este caso, creamos un `TextView` para el texto y un `ImageView` para el icono.

Despues creamos una clase que hara referencia a un Objecto, este objeto tiene dos propiedades `txt` e `imagen`

```
public class Modelo {

    String txt;
    String imagen;

    public Modelo(){
    }

    public Modelo(String txt, String imagen) {
        this.txt=txt;
        this.imagen=imagen;
    }

    public String getTxt() {
        return txt;
    }

    public String getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    public void setTxt(String txt){
        this.txt = txt;
    }

    public void setImagen(String imagen){
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }
}
```

Luego creamos el Custom Adapter, este tipo de clase te permite manejar la parte visual y los elementos del layout anteriormente creado para entregar los datos correspondientes.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Modelo> {

    private ArrayList<Modelo> dataSet;
    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt;
        ImageView imagen;    
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Modelo> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext=context;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Obtenemos el item de acuerdo a su posicion.
        Model dataModel = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            viewHolder.imagen = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagen);

            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }

        viewHolder.txt.setText(dataModel.getName());
        //En el caso que la imagen venga desde el webservice y ya la hayas seteado en la clase asincrona.
        //viewHolder.imagen.setImageResource(dataModel.getImagen());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Uno de los metodos mas importantes es el `getView`, este metodo es llamado por cada item que se crea en tu lista, aqui buscas los items dentro de tu layout, das el formato y entregar los datos.

Luego de obtener tus datos de manera asincrona, tal como lo haces tu, debes crear con ese resultado una lista de objetos pertenecientes a tu clase `Model` que creamos.

Reemplazar `List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();` por

```
ArrayList<Modelo> preguntas = new ArrayList<Modelo>();
//Parsea la respuesta obtenida por el Asynctask
JSONArray jsonArray = null;
try {
    jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
    try {
        preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String pregunta = null;
    try {
        Modelo pregunta = new Modelo();
        pregunta.txt = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta");
        //pregunta.img = preguntaDatos.getString("imagen");
        //En el caso que no fuese la imagen la que vuelve por el webservice puedes dar las imagenes que estimes conveniente
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    preguntas.add(pregunta);
}
adapter = new CustomAdapter(preguntas,getApplicationContext());
//Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);
mostrarr.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Modelo pregunta = preguntas.get(position);

        System.out.println("Haz hecho click en "+pregunta.getTxt());
    }
});
```

En este ejemplo le di una imagen por defecto a tu item, que es `@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info`, pero tambien deje comentado como deberia ser en el caso que fuese una imagen desde el webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias preguntas con algo similar a lo que deseas, en este caso tener una vista personalizada que tenga un icono y texto, para esto puedes crear un layout layout con los elementos que deseas, por ejemplo:

`item.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/foca" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Rehabilitate Sick and Injured Seal Pups\World Oceans Week\n$1 means 1 pound of fish for a  hungry seal pup"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#879BA6"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

El cual generaría una vista que contiene una imagen (icono) y un texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta vista será inflada por medio de tu adapter personalizado dentro del método getView(),

Agrego unos tutoriales, uno de nuestros amigos de "hermosa programación", en donde pudes ver que simplemente necesitas una vista personalizada con los elementos deseados.

**[Listas Y Adaptadores En Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-listas-adaptadores/)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y otro llamado **[Cómo crear un adapter personalizado en Android](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/adapter-personalizado-en-android/)**