# Quiero cambiar la celda de un ListView de color segun un paramentro Android Studio

Tags: android, listview

Tengo un par de problemas con el ListView

1) En el ListView salen asignaturas y quiero que si estas tienen un aviso se marquen con un color distinto, ya sea cambiando el background o las letras de color. 
El parámetro lo recibo en un JSONArray. Y si este parámetro "avis" tiene valor "1" el background de esa celda sea de otro color.
Espero que me puedan ayudar.

2) Cada vez que hago click en un item de la ListView, vuelvo a atrás y y al volver a clickear en otro item se me carga la información del anterior. He intentado usar "notifydatachanged" pero no consigo que me funcione.

GRACIAAAAAS

```
public class Subjects_list extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
public static final String ip = "192.168.43.110";
public static Subjects ls;
private List<HashMap<String, String>> SubjectList = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView mListView;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "";
private static final String KEY_FULLNAME = "Nom complet";
private static final String KEY_INITIALS = "Inicials";
private static final String KEY_CREDITS = "Credits";
private static final String KEY_COORDINADOR = "Coordinador";
public String avis ="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subjects_list);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Portal.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    this.setTitle("LA TEVA MATRICULA");
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.subjectslist);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    new getSubjectslistAsynTask(this).execute(message);


}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Avis.class);
    TextView Initials = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.initials);
    String InitialsValue = Initials.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, InitialsValue);
    mListView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    startActivity(intent);
}

private class getSubjectslistAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    InputStream stream = null;
    String str = "";

    private getSubjectslistAsynTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Subjects_list.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Carregant...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            String str = loadFromNetwork(urls[0]);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);


            if ( str != null){

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject s = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String initials = s.getString("initials");
                    String fullname = s.getString("fullname");
                    String credits = s.getString("credits");
                    String coordinator = s.getString("coordinator");
                    avis = s.getString("avis");

                    HashMap<String, String> subject = new HashMap<>();

                    subject.put("initials",initials);
                    subject.put("fullname",fullname);
                    subject.put("credits",credits);
                    subject.put("coordinator",coordinator);
                    //subject.put("avis",avis);

                    SubjectList.add(subject);


                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

       // onLoaded(ls.listsubjects);


            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Subjects_list.this, SubjectList,
                    R.layout.activity_list_subjectsuser, new String[]{"initials","fullname",
                    "credits","coordinator","avis"}, new int[]{
                    R.id.initials,R.id.fullname, R.id.credits, R.id.coordinator,R.id.avis});

            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);





    }

}
```

Comment: Hola @AlbaEgeaCadiz para lograr lo que necesitas deberás de crear un adapter personalizado en lugar de SimpleAdapter. Te recomiendo la siguiente [lectura](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/adapter-personalizado-en-android/) si nunca has implementado un adapter personalizado. En el mismo tutorial tengo que decir que en el método getView() puedes cambiar el color del layout de cada item de la lista dependiendo de la condición que necesites.  Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Definitivamente debes usar un `Adapter` con elementos personalizados (No un SimpleAdapter) que en este caso serían los elementos del listado.

Como ejemplo la respuesta de @sioesi en la cual indica como crear un `CustomAdapter` :

[Listview con un icono y texto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40785/listview-con-un-icono-y-texto/40801#40801)

y dentro del método `getView()` de tu `Adapter` dependiendo de la propiedad del `JSONObject` pintar de background la celda de un color u otro:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = convertView;

    ...
    ...
    ...

    JSONObject s = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
    String avis = s.getString("avis");


    if (avis.equals("1") {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

    return view;

}
```