# Mi ListView no aparece en la app

Tags: android, android-listview

Desde ya un hace tiempo he estado buscando para poder solucionar este problema, he visto hilos relacionado a esto, pero son diferentes situaciones y no las he comprendido del todo, en fin.

Mi problema es que he creado este *ListView* en base a un video que vi, lo que sucede es que he estado usando una versión más nueva de *Android Studio* y algunas cosas han cambiado, por eso acudo a acá a ver que me aconsejan.

### El problema:

Creé el layout y lo que solicitaba el video, lo que pasa es que cuando ejecuto la app el espacio donde está el *ListView* no se muestra del todo. Creé dos vectores y la idea es que aparezca el título y un subtitulo en cada item, eso lo realicé en la clase anónima que me genera automáticamente el Android Studio:

El Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="#97C0EA"
    android:padding="8sp"
    android:textColor="#0B0B0B"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

El código de la Activity principal:

```
package com.example.listview_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView TV1;
    private ListView LV1;

    private String nombres [] = {"Patricia", "Samuel", "Victor", "Marget", "Jose", "Daniel"};
    private String subnombres [] = {"18", "29", "34", "45", "22", "21", "21"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TV1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvnf1);
        LV1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);

        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_lv1);
        LV1.setAdapter(adapter);

        LV1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                TV1.setText("La edad de " + LV1.getItemAtPosition(i) + "es" + subnombres[i] + " años");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Por ultimo acá está el código de la parte gráfica de la activity:

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnf1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="@string/txt1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="364dp"
        android:layout_height="269dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvnf1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.016" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: En esta imagen muestro la parte gráfica de la activity (lo que deseo que salga)]

[image: Esto me muestra al emular, no hay nada en esa parte de la activity]

Espero que haya quedado claro, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Mmm bueno y donde definiste el ListView?? te falta agregar esa parte del código que imagino se encuentra en tu `activity_main.xml`, también veo algunos huecos que se deben aclarar en tu pregunta para que se entienda mejor, seria mucho mejor que subas también una captura del como se ve al ejecutar, porque así como veo tu pregunta la verdad no la comprendo muy bien "bueno es lo que me sucede, puede que otro usuario la comprenda a la perfección sin necesidad de los datos que te solicito"

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias Israel, ya lo modifiqué ¿queda más claro ahora?

Comment: Perfecto, aunque de todas formas veo que ya te respondieron. Saludos ;)

Comment: Gracias, igualmente si puedes aportar alguna idea, se lo agradecería mucho, estoy super pegado con esta función de Android Studio, pude utilizar el Spinner y no me dio problemas, pero siguiendo las guías que encuentro, todas me muestran los mismos pasos pero no logro determinar si es un error mio y cual será.

Comment: Bueno el ejemplo que te dieron se ve bien, de todas formas puede que [éste enlace](https://naps.com.mx/blog/uso-de-un-listview-en-android/) te sirva ya que tiene un ejemplo sencillo y funcional

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Estas configurando incorrectamente tu Adapter, si usas un `ArrayAdapter` debes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
 ...
 ...
 //Convierte array a ArrayList
 List array_list = Arrays.asList(nombres); 
 //Inicializa Adapter.
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array_list);
 //Configura Adapter.
 LV1.setAdapter(adapter);
 ...
 ...
```

En cambio si deseas usar un layout personalizado debes crear un Adapter, revisa el ejemplo de esta pregunta:

[Listview con un icono y texto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40785/listview-con-un-icono-y-texto/40812#40812)

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, soy un poco nuevo en todo esto. Me basé en el video, nunca mencionó esa alternativa. Yo creé un adapter personalizado, por eso es que cuando inicializo el adapter no pongo el android, solo coloco el "R.layout.nombre de mi layout". Al menos eso decía el del video.

Esa guía crea una clase nueva llamada Custom Adapter, pero en varias guías no siguen ese paso, no se si la nueva versión ha hecho cambios o que me estoy equivocando en alguna parte.

Comment: Si usas un layout personalizado, debes usar un adapter personalizado. agrega tu custom adapter para ayudarte.

Comment: Lo intentaré, gracias por tu ayuda Jorge